# React-Table - How to combine useResizeColumns with sticky

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have resizable column of react-table . But I want to sticky-column with resizable column of react table .

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v7/examples/column-resizing?file=/src/App.js